# Can not set cookie in symfony app. How to fix it?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, cookies, symfony4

It can't set cookie on my PC.
I am working with my brother and it works for him on his PC

```
if (isset($_POST["stay_logged"])) {     
   setcookie("user_code", $user->getCode(), null, "/");
   $this->session->set("user_code", $user->getCode());
}
```

`isset($_POST["stay_logged"])` return true, "stay_logged" is name of checkbox.

> sign_in.html.twig

```
<form method='POST' class="sign_in_form">

    <input class="text-input text-input--material" name="login" placeholder="username or email" type="text">
    <br />
    <input class="text-input text-input--material" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password">

    {% if error is defined %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if error2 is defined %}
        {{ error2 }}
    {% endif %}

    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" name="stay_logged"/>     // my checkbox here
    <label for="stay_logged">Remember me</label>
    <input type='submit' class="sign_in_form_submit" value='log in' name="submit">
</form>
```

I can not see my cookie in any way.
Can you halp? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but when working with Symfony, you should rather use the `Response` object to set cookies, just like you're using `$this->session` instead of `$_SESSION`. In this case, try calling `$response->headers->setCookie(Cookie::create('user_code', $user->getCode()))`.

Comment: What have you tried to compare the browser where it's work to yours?

Comment: The problem was that argument time in setcookie was set to null. Thanks anyway.